# How to validate all items in WPF DataGrid column?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

Hello everyone I have a problem:
In WPF DataGrid I have an editable column and this colomn is measuring in percent (%), and sum of value in this column for all row should be not more than 100%. 
For example in grid we have 3 row, and in this column we have 20% 20% 60% values. 
in sum will be 100%.And user can change 60% into 75% the sum will be 
115%, the question is how to validate that sum of all items when user changes values?
Standard ValidationRule works only for one cell it doesn't help me.

Help me please with suggestion or solution of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using RIA for data manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to validate data in `DataGrid` you should validate the data source once the value in a `DataGridCell` has been changed. Let's say `DataSource` of your `DataGrid` is a `DataTable`. When the cell value changes go back to the `DataTable` and inside it iterate all column values to make sure sum is less than or equal to 100. If it is not let user know about the error

Comment: Yes but if changed value is submitted in datasource how make the rollback to previous value if uer press Esc for example.

Comment: for that take a look at options WPF for validation. On pressing escape key DataGrid will automatically revert to the last value. Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx and http://harishasanblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/datagrid-validation-using.html